# R package build error: '-std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options'

Tags: rcpp, rcpp11, rcpparmadillo

I am trying to build an R package which includes Rcpp and RcppArmadillo code. sourceCpp() works fine and everything runs smoothly, but when I try to build the package I get:  "This file requires compiler and library support for the
ISO C++ 2011 standard. This support is currently experimental, and must be
enabled with the -std=c++11 or -std=gnu++11 compiler options."

Including RcppArmadillo and Rcpp11 in the description file does not seem to help (see below)

My description file includes:

```
Imports:
  Rcpp (>= 0.12.13),
  RcppArmadillo (>= 0.7.900.2.0),
  Rcpp11 (>=    3.1.1.0),
  data.table
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo, Rcpp11
```

I've not included the two .cpp files as they are fairly long, but obviously the issue seems to be the use of C++11 syntax.

Comment: What package? What does the documentation say? What compiler are you using? What platform? No detail given here.

Comment: You approximately never want both the (actively maintained) `Rcpp` package and the somewhat "dormant" (in the Monty Python parrot skit sense) `Rcpp11`.  And you turn C++11 on via either `src/Makevars*` or `SystemRequirements`, see Writing R Extensions or _many_ existing CRAN packages for more.

Answer (score 4):

`Rcpp11` is **not** `Rcpp`. Said in another way, `Rcpp11` and `Rcpp` are two separate *R* packages that provide the "glue" between *R* and *C++* objects. As a result, they have fundamentally different APIs.

Removing `Rcpp11` from the `DESCRIPTION` file should allow everything to work.

```
Imports:
  Rcpp (>= 0.12.13),
  RcppArmadillo (>= 0.7.900.2.0),
  data.table
LinkingTo: Rcpp, RcppArmadillo
```

To enable *C++ 11* use in both `src/Makevars` and `src/Makevars.win`:

```
CXX_STD = CXX11 # Required for C++11
PKG_CXXFLAGS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) 
PKG_LIBS = $(SHLIB_OPENMP_CXXFLAGS) $(LAPACK_LIBS) $(BLAS_LIBS) $(FLIBS)
```

**Note:** The latter two lines are required for `RcppArmadillo`. For an example package that uses *C++-11* please see: https://github.com/r-pkg-examples/rcpp-cpp11-usage

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding the purpose of the `Rcpp11` package.  Could you describe a use case?

Comment: There really isn't a use case for `Rcpp11` due to its dormant development status. With this being said, `Rcpp11` was designed to improve how the transference between _R_ and _C++_ objects occurred by exploiting C++11 and greater language features. Though, this would result in deprecated support for C++98 features. However, that has yet to occur due to a majority of the platforms still shipping old compilers.

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution on [Dirk's post](https://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/rcpp-and-c++11-c++14-c++17/). In the Makevars and Makevars.win files the option

```
CXX_STD = CXX11
```

was out-commented. Include this option (delete the '#') and it builds no problem.